# Betfair, how to retrieve MATCH_ODDS, price , inplay through the Betfairs api

Tags: betfair

This is my code and it does not seem to get what i want.It just presents the number of matches having match odds whereas i want the odds and price data

```
header = {'X-Application' : 'APP_KEY_HERE', 'X-Authentication':'SESSION_TOKEN' ,'content-type' : 'application/json' }


url="https://api.betfair.com/exchange/betting/json-rpc/v1"header = { 'X-Application' : 'APP_KEY_HERE', 'X-Authentication' : 'SESSION_TOKEN' ,'content-type' : 'application/json' }

jsonrpc_req='{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "SportsAPING/v1.0/listMarketTypes", "params": {"filter": {"textQuery":"Tennis"}}, "id": 1}'

response = requests.post(url, data=jsonrpc_req, headers=header)

print(json.loads(response.text))
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using the listMarketTypes endpoint. For prices, you need to call listMarketBook along with a PriceProjection, OrderProjection and MatchProjection:

https://docs.developer.betfair.com/display/1smk3cen4v3lu3yomq5qye0ni/listMarketBook